# Secondary DNS different SOA record

Tags: dns-zone, ns-record, soa-record

we are managing our DNS data at Azure DNS. They provide 4 NS for redundancy, but just two days ago the whole Azure DNS service went down for a few hours, and all of our services with it as well. Now i'm looking for a better redundancy for such a worst case scenario.

Unfortunately Azure DNS does not support outgoing zone transfer to a secondary NS hosted by a different provider. But they provide a tool for exporting all data of a zone into a zone file.

Amazon Route 53 gives me the option, to import such a zone file. But for this i have to recreate that zone for my domain at Amazon first. And this leads to a different SOA record (and also 4 different NS entries).

My plan was to use both services (Azure and Amazon), and take from both two NS:

- MyDomain NS1 -> Azure
- MyDomain NS2 -> Amazon
- MyDomain NS3 -> Azure
- MyDomain NS4 -> Amazon

As i synchronize the zone data between the 2 providers over export / import by myself, i don't see a problem in terms of accurate DNS data. But the SOA and the NS records for the domain are not consistent.

What are the implications in such a szenario? Could that lead to problems with spam prevention or other services, who query DNS data for a domain?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that intermixing two providers here has no benefit: it is a set, not a list, and most authoritative nameservers will return these records in random order each time. Not very much relevant to your problem, but it is an error often made (thinking it is a list).

Comment: Wow! This is a 2016 post and I can tell you that the situation has not changed. It happened twice for my Org. And worst is that they do not allow AFXR, which prevented us from having a secondary zone. BTW, Amazon Route53 also doesn't allow Zone transfer, but R53 is surely more resilient DNS than Azure's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally wrote this as a comment, but honestly, I think it's really your best course of action.

Your DNS provider lost all its marbles for several hours and it won't support secondary DNS off-premises, and your response is to try to *hack around it*? I'd be curious to know what Azure would have to do to actually lose your business; shoot your dog, maybe? Myself, I'd be running for the exit so fast no-one would see the blur. **It's time to change your DNS provider to one that doesn't suck.**

Comment: Fair enough. But all DNS service providers i evaluated are operating in the same way, they give you multiple NS from there own network. Can you recommend me one provider who has this option of a secondary NS off-premise with a fair price?

Comment: I have never come across one that *doesn't* support zone transfers, but I roll my own DNS servers, and in any case we don't do service recommendations around here, so: no, I'm sorry, but I can't.  The usual practice is to swap 2ary DNS between yourself and a fellow sysadmin, or two, at a neighbouring company. - not everything has to be bought as SaaS!

Comment: Thanks for your time MadHatter. The reason for us to rely on a SaaS provider for DNS services is to outsource the responsibility for product exploits, DNS Floods aso. As DNS services are crucial (we just learnt it the hard way) i think, this is justifiable.

Comment: I entirely agree that your DNS is operation-critical.  My personal feeling is that critical services are the ones *best* kept in-house.  That said, it is of course your call what to outsource, but If you must outsource critical services, you will want hard, expensive-to-breach SLAs in place.  If you don't have those, honestly, you haven't done due-diligence for your outsourcing.  In the end, DNS has a mechanism in place for dealing with outage - distributed secondaries - and a provider that doesn't support them is only half a DNS provider.

Comment: As suggested by MadHatter we change our DNS provider to avoid this hack. Still interested in the technical answer to my initial quesstion.

Comment: I am at a similar stage as user82563. Experience with Azure DNS has been really painful. To make matters worst, both the cloud providers do not support Zone transfer (Azure, AWS).